# Regex pattern to check if anything other than space character exists

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a pattern matcher for anything other than space, that is it should return true if I find anything other than **space** character, in the entry. I have tried using

```
String s = "[^ \s]"
```

as the pattern matcher but it complains as error. What is the correct string to use to generate the pattern matcher?

Comment: The Javadoc for the Pattern class lists most of the things you can put in a Java regular expression, including `\S` for non-space.

Answer (score 2):

Use capital `S`.

```
  String regex= "\\S"
```

**Note:** Your code complain error because you should use double `\\` inside String.

Comment: this will match for if space exists right? I want to check if the entry contains any character *other than* space.

Comment: Yes, it will detect any character other than space.

Comment: So, what should I do?

Comment: Why does the it has to be captial S?

Answer (score 1):

Look for at least one non-space anywhere in the input:

```
.*\S.*
```

In java:

```
if (input.matches(".*\\S.*"))
    // there is at least one non-space character
```

Or just negate the (simpler) test for all spaces:

```
if (!input.matches("\\s*"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern

```
pattern= "(\S)+"
```

Comment: FYI java doesn't use slashes to delimit regex

Answer (score 0):

> it should return true if I find anything other than space character, in the entry.

You don't need any regex for this. You can use:

```
if (!string.replace(" ", "").isEmpty()) {...}
```

This will return true if there is any non-space character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

this could help you

```
String regex= "\\S"
```